# Is it possible to specify shell verbs at the command line?

Tags: shell, cmd, shellexecute

Using ShellExecute API you can specify a verb, e.g. 'open' or 'print'. Is it possible to do the same thing from the command line?

Comment: Which shell? What command line?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://www.naughter.com/shelexec.html

Comment: Yep, I think that's the best you can do. Thanks.